# Using R - Need advice predicting next year based on irregular time-series

Tags: r, predict

I need advice with regards to the following inquiry: "Based on your observations, what could you say about the **load** for the same months in year 2019?"

The str()/head() of the df looks like this:

```
data.frame':    683 obs. of  10 variables:
$ Route       : chr  "A" "B" "A" "A" ...
$ FlightNumber: int  770 279 128 235 434 543 556 663 770 279 ...
$ Capacity    : int  375 345 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 345 ...
$ Booked      : int  379 314 374 379 373 377 379 378 379 294 ...
$ DDate       : Date, format: "2018-05-01" "2018-05-01" "2018-05-02" "2018-05-03" ...
$ Year        : num  2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
$ Month       : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ Day         : int  1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 ...
$ Hour        : int  12 20 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 20 ...
$ load        : num  1.011 0.91 0.997 1.011 0.995 ...
```

`Route  FlightNumber  Capacity  Booked  DDate  Year   Month Day Hour load(=Booked/Capacity)
1 A               770      375    379 2018-05-01 2018     5   1   12    1.0106667
2 B               279      345    314 2018-05-01 2018     5   1   20    0.9101449
3 A               128      375    374 2018-05-02 2018     5   2   12    0.9973333
4 A               235      375    379 2018-05-03 2018     5   3   12    1.0106667
5 A               434      375    373 2018-05-04 2018     5   4   12    0.9946667
6 A               543      375    377 2018-05-05 2018     5   5   12    1.0053333`

If I plot the data, it looks like this: [geom_point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6K3E.png)

**UPDATE**: I ended up doing the following:

```
dat_A <- test %>% select(Route, DDate, load) %>% filter(Route == "A")
ts_A <- ts(dat_A$load, start = c(2017,5), end = c(2018,11), frequency = 1*12)
forecast(ts_A, h=12) %>% plot()
```

[Predicted outcome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48W8R.png)

```
#Double checking
fit <- auto.arima(ts_A)
summary(fit)
predict <- forecast(fit,n=1)
plot(predict)

plot.ts(predict$residuals)
qqnorm(predict$residuals) 
acf(predict$residuals)
```

Does the prediction seem sound? Looks rather flat even though I also tried train(1:480)/validat(481:611) via arima then forecast with a RMSE of 0.036...

Comment: I'm not sure you will get a good answer as it feels like you are asking for someone to do your assignment, but you should try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as it is really a question about how to do statistics, albeit in R.

Comment: it depends on what your "teacher" wants you to investigate, learn, understand. From what I get the question is to study the load values on an annual basis and compare them. So you could start with a histogram computing the mean and variance per year. Then you can draw according to timestamps with ts() for example, by group etc.. see if there is seasonability and how it compares from one year to the other, a simple split of the data for the year and the summary() will already give information. etc..

Comment: If you post on stats, and don't get a response, I will post something :)

Comment: It appears to be an irregular time series (e.g., two observations on May 1, but only one in subsequent days). Either you should use a package like `zoo` for irregular ts, or `summarize` the data by day, so you have one load observation per day.

Comment: heh, good thing I have until Thursday to crack the code :p

Comment: I think you are trying to predict Booked based on the date. Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: I'm trying to predict load(%) for an equivalent period in 2019. Thx for the feedback to all, once I crack it i'll report back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try. I can give you a direction to generate a time-series using the following function. First load your data say it is `df` and it has the column `Booked` so you can use the following method to generate a time-series which can be easily fit.

```
ts_data = ts(df$Booked, start = c(2017,1), end = c(2018,12), frequency = 12)
```

Now you can simply apply time-series prediction on this `ts_data` to predict the value of 2019. I am leaving rest of the code for you. Thank you!!

Comment: Thx! Great nudge ;p

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `vector` or `data.frame` into a time series, you could use:

```
dat <- as.ts(as.matrix(dat))
```